# Динамические поля формы и Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть таблица в которой динамические создаются строки с input (календарь) эти поля можно перемещать (`Drag and Drop`).

Всё вроде работает и события навешиваются на input, но при нажатии на кнопку добавить, значения всех input сбрасываютя.

Вот код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id_num = 1;

  $('#table-drop').on('click', '.plus', function() {

    $('.tr-plus').before(

      '<tr id="dateId-' + id_num + '" class="new-tr">' +
      '<td class="dragHandle" >&nbsp;</td>' +
      '<td><input class="date_pic form-control"> </td>' +
      '<td></td>' +
      '<td><span class="btn  btn-danger minus pull-right">-</span></td>' +
      '</tr>'
    );

    id_num++;

    droper(); // Функция DragAndDrop
    calendar(); // Функция выбора даты и времени

  });

  //    Delete row
  $(document).on('click', '.minus', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    console.log("Delete row");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="table-drop" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" class="table">
  <tr class="tr-plus">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><span class="btn btn-success plus pull-right">Добавить строку</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема скорее всего кроется в том, что .before() взаимодействует с существующими tr элементами, сбрасывая input value.

Стоит попробовать prepend или же реализовать state объект для input значений. Тем самым имея возможность заполнять input после добавления новой строки в таблице.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/skorolchuk/pen/PaJBXb)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                 
       
  $('.add').click(function () {
    var $newRow = $('<div class="row">'+
   '<div class="content"><input type="text"/></div>'+
    '<div class="remove"></div>'+
  '</div>');  
    
    $('.container').prepend($newRow);
    
    $newRow.find('.remove').click(function() {
      $newRow.remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 98vh;
  width: 98vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 30%;
}

.container.center {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  max-height: 50vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.row > * {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.remove {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #7fe020f1;
  border: 5px solid #7ff020a1;
  padding-left: px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 28px;
  border-radius: 35%;
}

.remove::before {
  content: '-';
}

.remove:hover {
  border: 5px solid #eef020a1;
}

.add::before {
  content: '+';
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  display: block;
}

.add {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: -340px;
  width: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #7fe040f1;
  border: 5px solid #efe040a1;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 28px;
  border-radius: 35%;
}

.add:hover {
  border: 5px solid #2ef020a1;
}

input[type=text] {
  height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container center">
  <div class="add"></div>
</div>
```